# how to get json ajax data fast and store it in localstorage and display it in jquery mobile listview

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-waypoints

when I call ajax to my server I got 1000 up data, 
I store that data in my local storage and display it in jQuery mobile list-view, 
but this take almost 50-60 sec to display or load data. how to make this process fast?

Here is my code:

```
var PollChallengeVoterDataUrl = ROOT+'testmaster/view/'+intCLMid+'/'+intCLTid+'/?UserId='+intUserId+'&UserRole='+intUserRole;
var data = "CampaignId="+IntCampaignId;

jQuery.ajax({
    url: PollChallengeVoterDataUrl,
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'Cconnect',
    data: data,
    success: function(response,request)
    {
        var statusresult=response.success;

        if(statusresult)
        {
            var data_arr = response.pollChallengeDetail[0];
            var data_len = response.pollChallengeDetail[0]['pollChallengeCount'];

            localStorage.removeItem(PollChallengeVoterList);
            if(data_len > 0)
            {
                $.each(data_arr, function(k, v) {

                    if(k == 0)
                    {

                    }
                    addToStorage(k,v,PollChallengeVoterList);
                });
            }
        }
    },
    error: function(e){
        alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
});
$.mobile.changePage('test.html', { transition:"slide" ,changeHash : true });
```

Test.html Display Code

```
 <div data-role="content">   
 <ul data-role="listview" id="pollChallengeVoterList" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true"></ul>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
```

test.js Code

```
var strDataResult = hasInStorage("PollChallengeCount",PollChallengeVoterList);
var strDataList = '';
$("#pollChallengeVoterList").html(strDataList);
var arrMainDataDetail = getArrayStorage(PollChallengeVoterList);

var intDataCount = arrMainDataDetail.pollChallengeCount;
for(j = 0; j < intDataCount; j++)
{
var intClmId = arrMainDataDetail.CLMid;
var intCvdId = arrMainDataDetail[j].CVDId;
var intCltId = arrMainDataDetail[j].CLTId;
var intPollChallengeVoterId = arrMainDataDetail[j].VoterId;
if(arrMainDataDetail[j].Voted == 0)
{
    var intFlg = 1;
}
else
{
    var intFlg = 0;
}

if(arrMainDataDetail[j].Challenged==1)
{
    var strChallengedColor = "#9F1335" ;
}
else
{
    var strChallengedColor = "" ;
}

if(arrMainDataDetail[j].AptUnitNo == "")
{
    strAddressRecord =arrMainDataDetail[j].AddressLine1;
}
else
{
    strAddressRecord =arrMainDataDetail[j].AddressLine1+' ,  # '+arrMainDataDetail[j].AptUnitNo;
}

if(arrMainDataDetail[j].Challenged==1)
{
    strVoterClass = "voted";
    strVoterStatus ='Challenged';
}
else
{
    if(arrMainDataDetail[j].Voted == 0)
    {
        strVoterClass = "voted";
        strVoterStatus ='Voted';
    }
    else
    {
        strVoterStatus ='Undo</span><span class="ui-li-count unvoted">Voted</span>';

    }
}

$('#pollChallengeVoterList').append('<li data-theme="c" data-icon="false"><a href="javascript:void(0)" style="color :'+strChallengedColor+'" data-transition="slide" onclick=ajaxupdatevote("'+intClmId+'","'+intCvdId+'","'+intCltId+'","'+intPollChallengeVoterId+'","'+intFlg+'","'+j+'")>'+arrMainDataDetail[j].LastName+', '+arrMainDataDetail[j].FirstName+'<span class="address" style="color :'+strChallengedColor+'">'+strAddressRecord+'</span><span class="ui-li-count '+strVoterClass+'">'+strVoterStatus+'</span></a></li>');
}

$("#pollChallengeVoterList").listview("refresh");
```

Comment: You would have to show us your code for us to have even a prayer of helping.  Also, you need to figure out how much of the 50-60 sec is waiting for the ajax call to return the data and how much of it is displaying the data.  There are slow and fast ways to add lots of HTML to the DOM.  If the issue is your ajax call, then that will be either your server response time or the amount of data being transfered.

Comment: my ajax call time takes 15 Sec in most cases

Comment: @SanGustavo i think you server side code is not good and that is why it takes lot of time. and paste your code. it ll be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there isn't anything much you can do here. If I understood you correctly you are displaying a listview of 1000 items and this is a problem.

Think about it, you are forcing jQuery Mobile to generate and enhance a huge listview. By some measurements jQuery Mobile works best with listview of max. 50-60 items.

To fix this problem you will need to redesign your listview logic. First pull only 50 items from a server. Second implement a pagination. Basically you will need to send one more parameter to a server and it is a page number, use it to calculate which data range you should send back.

On a client side you need also to implement pagination. There are two possible solutions. You can do it with buttons, like on a normal web page. This is probably easiest solution but at the same time it is not the best.

Best solution would be to pull new set of data when page bottom has been reached. This cn be easily done. I will even give you 2 working examples of how this can be achieved. You can implement listview infinite-scroll with a help of a jQuery plugin called **[Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)**. It can be used to detect listview has reached bottom, it will then trigger an event which can be used to pull another set of dynamic data and enhancement process will start again.

This will detect bottom end:

```
$('#example-offset-pixels').waypoint(function() {
    //notify('100 pixels from the top');
}, { offset: 100 });
```

Or you can take a look at my older example and see how it can be done manually (I prefer this solution over waypoints, it has a better bottom detection): **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Bn2Du/)**

Comment: hey "Gajotres" can you give me your proper code please... i implemented your code using jsfiddle but it doesn't work properly. it calls ajax at every scrole

Comment: as of i edit my code in jsfiddle its works perfect as your example but the same code i add in my site it calls ajax on every ajax

Comment: First you have to understand this is a proper code, if it works in jsFiddle that means it is a functional implementation. If it is not a problem tell me on what browser/platform are you testing it. And if it is possible mail me your code and I will test it directly. My mail is: dragan.gaic@gmail.com

Comment: I made a slight change to my code, it will trigger ajax call if you scroll 5px to a bottom border. I have also tested it on Android. I will soon also do it on a iPad.